# is it possible to push UIVIEWCONTROLLER from root UISplitController?

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

1. I am developing for iPad & designing worflow of app.
2. I know how to push View to master & detail view of split view but
   i want one view to be completely & separately display (taking complete screen) & once user
   click button on pushed view, user get navigate back to
   UisplitViewController.
3. I kept UISplitViewController as root controller as suggested
   by doc.

**So is it possible to push UIViewController from UISplitViewController?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to get a single view to display in a UISplitViewController, you will need to hide the master.  You can do this by modifying the UISplitViewDelegate This is what I use:

```
BOOL hideMaster = NO;
- (void)hideMaster
{
    hideMaster = YES;
    UISplitViewController *sv = (UISplitViewController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    [sv.view setNeedsLayout];

    [sv willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] duration:0];

}
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{

    return hideMaster;
}
```

So, if you've got a UINavigationController in the detail screen, it's just a matter of hiding the master and pushing your other view into the detail panel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i got the theme that hiding master view & pushing required view to detail view will do the job for me.